# Programmatic access to vTiger?

Tags: java, vtiger

I'm about to start setting up programmatic access to vTiger 5 from a Java application, and I was looking for a client library that will interface with the REST API. The `vtwsclib` library seems to be the right (only?) way to go. It looks like v1.0 was released in 2008 and over the course of a year, the version moved along to 1.4

There doesn't seem to have been any changes to the library since, except for a couple of weeks ago (2014-08-26) v1.5 was released. There's no documentation for it, either on the download page (like the other versions) or in the downloadable itself (that I can see).

So what's the deal with this new version? Is it suitable for working with vTiger 5? I'm considering migrating to vTiger 6. Is the the 1.5 library targeted at vTiger 6? Does it make no difference which version of the lib I use?

Answer (score 0):

According to my findings, there are no significative changes in the .php, .js or .py code of version 1.5 compared to 1.4, and for the Java code it appears most changes are related to the project files and not the code itself. 
I obtained the "diff" by extracting 1.4 to an empty git repository and subsequently adding 1.5 to it. 
The repository is hosted at [this link](https://github.com/maggix/vtwsclib) so you can examine by yourself.

Based on this, the answer to your question is that you can use it for Vtiger 5 as little or no changes seems to have been made. Please improve this answer if needed.